# Convert string to EDM Date in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to convert a date string to EDM Date Time in python? My date will be in a string format, either dd.mm.yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy
How to convert it to EDM DateTime format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS ,
e.g.

input date - 03.08.2023
output date - 2023-08-03T00:00:00

Thanks